# Number of Motzkin paths which are not Dyck path

Tags: co.combinatorics

A Dyck path can only move up or down, without crossing the $x$-line.

A Motzkin path is a Dyck path which can also do level steps.

Are there any informations (such as closed-form, asymptotic behavior etc...) on the number of Motzkin paths of length $2n$ which are not Dyck paths ?